# Both Stackoverlfow and Google APIs require the App key to be passed as a query parameter. Why isn't this a security flaw?

Tags: api, http, security, authentication, authorization

Most of the **Google** APIs (Maps/Places for instance) and **Stackoverflow** API (when not using OAuth, thus not impersonating a user) will require a `key` parameter to be passed. This `key` identifies the application and is used mainly to control the quota.

What I can't understand is why this is considered a better design decision than passing the `key` as an HTTP header over SSL. At least I don't think the later would expose my `key` to a potential `man-in-the-middle` nor allowing them to replay my request 10000 times expiring my daily quota.

Is there any very good reason for this apparently poor design decision?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you concerned about it being a parameter vs a header? or over the channel?

Comment: Please describe your threat model. It sounds like we're only contemplating https communication, where the cert CA chain verifies ok. A MitM attack is launched by a "powerful" adversary, e.g. a coffee shop WAP owner. What powers do you imagine your adversary has, and what advantage would he reap from compromising the app key? How would things be different if the key was passed inside or outside of the request headers? The tradeoffs can be tricky, so it helps to write down the assumptions.